# Error with $(window).height in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the `$(window).height` in jquery and using firebug to print out the value and it is saying the value is `8` instead of `800`.

The `$(window).width` is working fine. Any ideas how I can fix this.

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/122/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `height()`, and `width()` function, not the property.

Comment: I am trying to get the height of the screen tho

Comment: The dimensions of the screen is: `screen.height`, `screen.width`
(native js)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

- Try closing Firebug and use an alert box instead. It may be that Firebug is causing your window to shrink. Also try maximizing Firebug into a new window
- I would recommend is making sure your version of jQuery is up to date. Or, if you're using version 1.9, downgrade to 1.8.
- If all else fails, you can resort to plain old JavaScript: `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`

Comment: (edited answer) Have you tried upgrading jQuery to the latest, or trying version 1.8?